# Migration involving model with ancestry fail because has_ancestry method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I use the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem in my Rails 4 application. My model with ancestry looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_ancestry
  has_many :company_products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :company_products

  validates_presence_of :name

end
```

This code works. I can manage it in the ActiveAdmin interface and even could make a nested checkboxes-set for a HABTM relationship to such model.

However, when trying to run a migration with this code (file name: 20160412201550_add_code_to_products.rb):

```
class AddCodeToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    change_table :products do |table|
      table.string :code, limit: 100, null: false, default: ''
    end
    reversible do |direction|
      direction.up do
        {passage: 'Passage', harbor: 'Harbor'}.each do |k, v|
          index = 0
          Product.where(name: v).each do |product|
            code = index > 0 ? "#{k}#{index}" : k
            product.update! code: code
          end
        end
      end
      direction.down do
        # nothing here
      end
      add_index :products, :code, unique: true
    end
  end

end
```

It explodes when reaching the sentences involving `Product`, by yelling:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `has_ancestry' for #

The stack trace shows additiona lines. The relevant one is:

```
/home/myusername/Proyectos/myproject/app/models/product.rb:3:in `<class:Product>'
```

Which is the `has_ancestry` line in the `Product` model class definition.

So, in brief:

- This works perfectly if I run the standard server (`rails s`).
- This explodes if I run migrations. **NO**: calling `require 'ancestry'` does not fix it, since it raises another exception: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- ancestry`.

How can I make ancestry be loaded for migration context?

Comment: interesting.  did you try `require 'ancestry` in your migration?

Comment: Yes (correctly quoted, but yes)

Comment: heh.. sorry I misread your last statement and was trying to understand why you weren't requiring - I see now -- quirky

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `ancestry` is buggy. Fixed it in the gemfile:

```
gem 'ancestry', require: true
```

To have it available on migrations context